# jquery uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .[object Object] with keypress function

Tags: javascript, jquery

uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .[object Object]

```
[Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function cv(a){return f...indexOf(".")>=0&&(i=h.split("."),h=i.
jquery.min.js (line 16)
```

Has anyone ever gotten this error?

This is what generates it.

```
$('input').live('keypress',function(){
    console.log('fdsdfs');  
});
```

When I execute in the console in jquery it initializes on all my inputs. When I type I get that error.

Comment: What is the browser and jQuery version.

Comment: Quite a few. Let me disable them and see if I can fix it. Ill get back to you.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was a problem with a plugin. I totaly forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time random errors in jQuery code base are caused by plugins or sending the wrong data type for the method. In you =r case the key event looks fine so look at the plugins.